# Android Google Maps Android Maven Plugin - No resource identifier found for attribute cameraTargetLat

Tags: android, eclipse, m2eclipse, m2e

I ve a Google Map Project in Spring Framework STS 3.5.1 with Android Maven Plugin 1.01.

Everything compiles fine  - no Errors are shown in my IDE. 
I' ve set up the googleplay_services_lib as a Libary Project for andoid.
The R Files are generated correctly.
The missing attributes are in the  com.googgle.android.gms R.Java File.

[image: Screenshot of IDE with References]

But when it comes to generate sources  maven fails when executing aapt

```
[DEBUG] D:\Programme\androis-sdks\build-tools\17.0.0\aapt.exe [package, -m, -J, D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\target\generated-sources\r, -f, --no-crunch, -M, D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\AndroidManifest.xml, -S, D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res, --auto-add-overlay, -A, D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\target\generated-sources\combined-assets, -I, D:\Programme\androis-sdks\platforms\android-19\android.jar, --output-text-symbols, D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\target]
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\multimap_demo.xml:29: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraTargetLat' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\multimap_demo.xml:29: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraTargetLng' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\multimap_demo.xml:29: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraZoom' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\multimap_demo.xml:38: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraTargetLat' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\multimap_demo.xml:38: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraTargetLng' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\multimap_demo.xml:38: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraZoom' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\multimap_demo.xml:54: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraTargetLat' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\multimap_demo.xml:54: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraTargetLng' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\multimap_demo.xml:54: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraZoom' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\multimap_demo.xml:63: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraTargetLat' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\multimap_demo.xml:63: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraTargetLng' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\multimap_demo.xml:63: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraZoom' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\options_demo.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraBearing' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\options_demo.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraTargetLat' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\options_demo.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraTargetLng' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\options_demo.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraTilt' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\options_demo.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraZoom' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\options_demo.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'mapType' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\options_demo.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'uiCompass' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\options_demo.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'uiRotateGestures' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\options_demo.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'uiScrollGestures' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\options_demo.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'uiTiltGestures' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\options_demo.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'uiZoomControls' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\options_demo.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'uiZoomGestures' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\split_street_view_panorama_and_map_demo.xml:36: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraTargetLat' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\split_street_view_panorama_and_map_demo.xml:36: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraTargetLng' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[INFO] D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\split_street_view_panorama_and_map_demo.xml:36: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraZoom' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
[DEBUG] ANDROID-040-000: Executed command: Commandline = cmd.exe /X /C "D:\Programme\androis-sdks\build-tools\17.0.0\aapt.exe package -m -J D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\target\generated-sources\r -f --no-crunch -M D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\AndroidManifest.xml -S D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res --auto-add-overlay -A D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\target\generated-sources\combined-assets -I D:\Programme\androis-sdks\platforms\android-19\android.jar --output-text-symbols D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\target", Result = 1
[ERROR] Error when generating sources.
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:745)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.execute(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:278)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
Caused by: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.ExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C "D:\Programme\androis-sdks\build-tools\17.0.0\aapt.exe package -m -J D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\target\generated-sources\r -f --no-crunch -M D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\AndroidManifest.xml -S D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res --auto-add-overlay -A D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\target\generated-sources\combined-assets -I D:\Programme\androis-sdks\platforms\android-19\android.jar --output-text-symbols D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\target", Result = 1
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.CommandExecutor$Factory$DefaultCommandExecutor.executeCommand(CommandExecutor.java:252)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:741)
    ... 23 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.987 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-06-04T09:02:15+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/309M
```

I 've then copied and executed the aapt command in verbose mode from command line and there I could see that is looking for the missing Attributes in `com.pekam.myandroid` but not in `com.google.android.gms.R`

```
D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\MyAndroid\res\layout\multimap_demo.xml:29: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraTargetLat
' in package 'com.pekam.myandroid'
```

Why is the compiler looking in **com.pekam.myandroid** and not in **com.google.android.gms**

How can I get rid of this Error

here is my **pom xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.pekam.myandroid</groupId>
    <artifactId>myandroid</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>        
     <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-tasks</artifactId>
      <version>v1-rev33-1.18.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.0-rc</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
          <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>android</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
           <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client-android</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>
         <dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>
      <version>v2-rev70-1.18.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
      <version>v2-rev126-1.18.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-android-rest-template</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
<!--     <dependency> -->
<!--         <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId> -->
<!--         <artifactId>spring-android-auth</artifactId> -->
<!--         <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version> -->
<!--     </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-android-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
          <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <source>1.6</source>
               <target>1.6</target>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <sdk>
                  <path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</path>
                   <platform>19</platform>
               </sdk>
               <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
           </configuration>
           <extensions>true</extensions>
       </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```